# How can i include an specific form based on the selected option of <select> in Laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, html-select, laravel-blade

I have an  with 3 options. these options come from the database.
Every item in  has an specific own form. I want that if i select option1, it shows form1 on the same page. so not switchting to other url
I thought about using the @include in blade but the function runs instant if i open the page while i have made some if/else statements.

im not sure if i explain it perfectly but here is the code :

Selectbox:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control col-lg-4" name="object" id="object">                     
          <option value="" disabled selected>Maak een keuze</option>
              @foreach($house_statuses as $status)
                  <option value="{{$status->house_status_description}}"> 
                         {{$status->house_status_description}}
                 </option>
           @endforeach
   </select>
 </div>
```

My idea to include the form in Jquery/js

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#object').on('change', function () {

        var optionValue = $(this).val();
        // var optionText = $("#object option:selected").value;
        $.ajax({
            url: "/ajax/get/" + optionValue.toLowerCase() + "", success: 
              function (result) {
                $('#col-10').text('@include('house.form.huur')')
            }
        });

    });
    });
</script>
```

The ajax call is for getting my variables that belong to the form

Hope someone has a suggestion what im doing wrong or what i can do better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `return` statement of the called controller method (`/ajax/get/" + optionValue.toLowerCase()`) must be your form HTML.

Then in your AJAX success callback, correct `$('#col-10').text('@include('house.form.huur')')` by `$('#col-10').html(result)`. You may have to specify the `dataType` as stated on the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: Its glitching with the layout. but its what i want. Thanks